# jQuery findClass and display what this class is?

Tags: jquery

I’m trying to find an element with the class “active” and then echo what other classes it has, and only select the start of the string.

#### HTML:

```
<div class="cmButtons">
    <ul>
        <li class="cmAuto_btn a active">Auto BTN</li>
        <li class="cmPro_btn a">Pro BTN</li>
        <li class="cmFocus_btn a">Focus BTN</li>
        <li class="cmBright_btn a">Bright BTN</li>
        <li class="cmLow_btn a">Low BTN</li>
        <li class="cmMotion_btn a">Motion BTN</li>
        <li class="cmCustom_btn a">Custom BTN</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```css
#result{background:#EEE;border:1px solid #CCC;margin:20px 0;height:30px;line-height:30px;width:500px;}
```

#### Javascript (with jQuery):

```
if($('.cmButtons ul li').hasClass("active")){
    var activeLi = $(this).attr("class");
    $('#result').html(activeLi);
}
```

[Demo on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xavi3r/tGypJ/).

So, based on the fiddle;

The active element is: `<li class="cmAuto_btn a active">Auto BTN</li>`

jQuery should output the class as: `cmAuto_btn a active`

jQuery should then modify the string to render as `cmAuto_btn`

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to change the class of the `LI` from `cmAuto_btn a active` to `cmAuto_btn`, OR just want to print the class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to iterate over the set of matched elements with `each`. You can then split the class names on spaces, and get the first element of the resulting array:

```
$('.cmButtons ul li').each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
       var firstClass = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0];
    } 
});
```

Here's an [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/tGypJ/19/).

And here's an alternative, due to comments below (still using `each` in case there are multiple elements with class `active`):

```
$('.cmButtons ul li.active').each(function() {
    var firstClass = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0];
});
```

You should probably use this one, unless you also need to do something with elements that do not have the `active` class, in which case you can use the above example with an `else` block.

Comment: That updated example doesn't have that split code in it. Also why are you doing the "hasClass" rather than just makign your selector `.cmButtons ul li.active`?

Comment: @Chris - Oops, thanks, I've updated the link to the fiddle. I'm using the `hasClass` method simply because that's what the OP was using. Perhaps they need to do something else if the `li` does not have the class?

Comment: @James: Fair enough. Given the OP didn't know how to do it though I'd do it in the best way and then let him ask again if he needs something else. You don't want to encourage bad practices after all. :)

Comment: @Chris - Yeah, very true. I've updated the answer with your method.

Comment: @James: Cheers. You've earned my +1 now. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.cmButtons ul li').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("active"))
       {
       $('#result').html($(this).attr("class"));
       }
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tGypJ/12/

Comment: This gets the entire class name, which is not what was asked. The OP needs just the first class out of the list of classes.

Comment: Also see my comment to James on why are you using hasClass?

Answer (score 0):

in this part "`this`" not mean the Li but the document, because it is out of the jquery selector block, you can by approved in it when you print this `alert(this.location)`. so try this

```
$('.cmButtons ul li').each(function(idx, val) {
    if(val.hasClass("active")) {
       var activeLi = val.attr("class").split(" ")[0];
       $('#result').html(activeLi);
    } 
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about `this` not referring to the `li`... inside the `each` loop, `this` will refer to the current `li` element.

Comment: i dont mean inside the loop, it is about this example: http://jsfiddle.net/xavi3r/tGypJ/

Comment: Ahh I see. Sorry, I thought you meant inside the `each` loop because you were not using `this` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple ? :**

```
var activeClasses = $('.cmButtons ul li.active').attr('class');
$('#result').html(activeClasses);
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/Mpqfy/

---

*So you can use like :*

```
var active = $('.cmButtons ul li.active');
var activeClasses = active.attr('class');
$('#result').html(activeClasses);

active.doSomething();
```